# How to avoid java server from hanging when writing faster to a socket than the other side reads

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, server

I'm using a TCP java server to receive data from clients and send data back to the clients. The problem is that when the server writes faster to a client socket than the client can read, the server hangs/freezes and it won't process any of the data from the other clients anymore.

For example the server writes 3 kb/s to a client socket and the client can only read 1 kb/s. How do I recognize this, so I can close this socket and stop writing to it?

What is happening? Is data being buffered?

I use the following code to write data:

```
this.out_ = new PrintWriter(this.clientSocket_.getOutputStream(), true);

this.out_.print(msg);
```

**Edit: complete code**

Main.java

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;

public class Main
{
    static ServerSocket serverSocket_;
    static HashMap<String, ServerInformation> servers_;
    static int verboseLevel_;
    static int threadTimeout_;
    static int masterPort_;
    static int serverNumber_;
    static int socketTimeOut_;

    static {
        Main.serverSocket_ = null;
        Main.servers_ = new HashMap<String, ServerInformation>();
        Main.verboseLevel_ = 5;
        Main.threadTimeout_ = 10;
        Main.masterPort_ = 6510;
        Main.serverNumber_ = 1;
        Main.socketTimeOut_ = 6000;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        try {
            setupServerAndCleanup(Main.masterPort_);
            while (true) {
                handleIncomingConnection();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static void setupServerAndCleanup(final int port) throws IOException {
        (Main.serverSocket_ = new ServerSocket()).setReuseAddress(true);
        Main.serverSocket_.bind(new InetSocketAddress(Main.masterPort_));
        System.out.println("Server socket up and running on port " + Main.masterPort_);
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (Main.serverSocket_ != null) {
                    try {
                        Main.serverSocket_.close();
                        System.out.println("Server socket closed, port released");
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }));
    }

    static void handleIncomingConnection() throws IOException {
        final Socket clientSocket = Main.serverSocket_.accept();
        clientSocket.setSoTimeout(Main.socketTimeOut_);
        final ClientThread client = new ClientThread(clientSocket);
        client.start();
    }

}
```

ClientThread.java

```
import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.Reader;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;

    public class ClientThread extends Thread
    {
    Socket clientSocket_;
    String clientIp_;
    String serverIp_;
    ServerInformation server_;
    PrintWriter out_;
    BufferedReader in_;
    boolean prepareTermination_;
    boolean terminated_;
    private static final Pattern numberPattern;

    static {
        numberPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    }

    public ClientThread(final Socket sock) {
        this.clientSocket_ = sock;
        this.clientIp_ = this.clientSocket_.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString();
        this.serverIp_ = null;
        this.server_ = null;
        this.prepareTermination_ = false;
        this.terminated_ = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            this.out_ = new PrintWriter(this.clientSocket_.getOutputStream(), true);
            this.in_ = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket_.getInputStream()));

            long lastActionTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while (true) {

                if (this.in_.ready() || System.currentTimeMillis() - lastActionTime >= 1000 * Main.threadTimeout_) {
                    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastActionTime >= 1000 * Main.threadTimeout_) {
                        //this.logDebugMessage(3, "Thread was killed due to prolonged inactivity (" + Main.threadTimeout_ + " seconds)");
                        this.terminateThread();
                        return;
                    }

                    final String tempInputLine;
                    if(((tempInputLine = this.in_.readLine()) == null )){
                        this.terminateThread(); //end thread                        
                        return;             
                    }
                    else
                    {                   
                        lastActionTime = System.currentTimeMillis();                    
                        final String inputLine = tempInputLine.trim();
                        if (ClientThread.numberPattern.matcher(inputLine).matches()){
                        final int val = Integer.parseInt(inputLine);
                        switch (val) {
                          case 1: { //send data to other players
                                final int parseCount = Integer.parseInt(this.in_.readLine().trim());
                                final StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
                                for (int j = 0; j < parseCount; ++j) {
                                    msg.append(String.valueOf(this.in_.readLine().trim()) + "|");
                                }
                                for (final ClientThread thread2 : this.server_.ipToClientThread_.values()) {
                                    if (thread2 != this) {
                                        thread2.out_.print(msg);
                                        thread2.out_.flush();
                                    }
                                }
                                //this.logDebugMessage(5, "Packet for others: '" + msg.toString() + "'");
                                break;
                            }   

                            case 2: { //remove game server
                                //this.logDebugMessage(1, "A game server has been deleted, ip: " + ipServer);
                                Main.servers_.remove(this.server_.ip_);
                                this.serverIp_ = null;
                                for (final ClientThread thread : this.server_.ipToClientThread_.values()) {
                                    thread.prepareTermination_ = true;
                                }
                                this.terminateThread();
                                return;
                            }
                            case 3: { //connect new client
                                final String ipServer = this.in_.readLine().trim();
                                final String ipClient = this.in_.readLine().trim(); 
                                this.logDebugMessage(1, "A client wishes to connect to a server, client: " + ipClient + ", server: " + ipServer);
                                final ServerInformation info = Main.servers_.getOrDefault(ipServer, null);
                                if (info == null) {
                                    System.out.println("Connection to the server failed, no such server in the server list");
                                   this.out_.print("*" + 1 + "|" + 1 + "~" + "|");
                                   this.out_.flush();                                   
                                break;
                                }
                                this.server_ = info;
                                this.server_.ipToClientThread_.put(ipClient, this);
                                this.logDebugMessage(1, "Connection success");
                                this.logDebugMessage(5,"Map: " + this.server_.ipToClientThread_);
                                    this.out_.print("*" + 1 + "|" + 2 + "~" + "|");
                                    this.out_.flush();
                                break;
                            }         
                            case 4: { //disconnect client
                                final String ipClient = this.in_.readLine().trim();
                                this.server_.ipToClientThread_.remove(ipClient);
                                this.logDebugMessage(1, String.valueOf(ipClient) + " disconnected from the server at " + this.server_.ip_);
                                this.serverIp_ = null;
                                this.terminateThread();
                                return;
                            }                   

                            case 5: { //host create new game
                                if (Main.serverNumber_ > 1000000) {
                                Main.serverNumber_ = 10;    
                                }
                                Main.serverNumber_ += 1;                                
                                final String ipServer = Integer.toString(Main.serverNumber_); //unique server number
                                final String ipHost =  this.in_.readLine().trim(); //host 
                                final String name = this.in_.readLine().trim(); //Server name
                                final String description = this.in_.readLine().trim(); //class
                                final String servervar1 = this.in_.readLine().trim(); //max players
                                final String servervar3 = this.in_.readLine().trim(); //current lap
                                final String servervar4 = this.in_.readLine().trim(); //total laps
                                final String servervar5 = this.in_.readLine().trim(); //status
                                final String servervar6 = this.in_.readLine().trim(); //Password
                                final String servervar7 = this.in_.readLine().trim(); //Online version
                                final String servervar8 = this.in_.readLine().trim(); //Game server
                                final long servervar9 = System.currentTimeMillis(); //server creation time
                                //this.logDebugMessage(1, "A game server has been registered, ip: " + ipServer + ", name: " + name + ", description: " + description + ", servervar1: " + servervar1);
                                final ServerInformation gameServer = new ServerInformation(name, servervar1, servervar3, servervar4, servervar5, servervar6, servervar7, servervar8, servervar9, ipHost, ipServer, this.clientSocket_, this.out_, this.in_);
                                gameServer.description_ = description;
                                gameServer.ipToClientThread_.put(ipHost, this);
                                this.server_ = gameServer;
                                Main.servers_.put(ipServer, gameServer);
                                this.serverIp_ = ipServer;
                                break;
                            }                               
                            default: {
                                this.logDebugMessage(0, "Unrecognized case: '" + inputLine + "', " + val);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (inputLine.length() > 0) {
                        this.logDebugMessage(0, "Unformated '" + inputLine + "'");
                        if (this.server_ != null) {
                            this.server_.out_.print(inputLine);
                            this.server_.out_.flush();
                        }
                    }
                    if (this.prepareTermination_) {
                        this.terminateThread();
                        return;
                    }
                    continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                this.terminateThread();
            }
            catch (IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e3) {
            e3.printStackTrace();
            try {
                this.terminateThread();
            }
            catch (IOException e4) {
                e4.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    //debug messages
    void logDebugMessage(final int requiredVerbose, final String msg) {
        if (Main.verboseLevel_ >= requiredVerbose) {
            System.out.println("[" + this.clientIp_ + "]  " + msg);
        }
    }

    //terminate thread
    void terminateThread() throws IOException {
        if (!this.terminated_) {
            if (this.serverIp_ != null) {
                Main.servers_.remove(this.serverIp_);
            }
            this.clientSocket_.close();
            this.in_.close();
            this.out_.close();
            this.logDebugMessage(3, "Cleanup successful");
            this.terminated_ = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Each client communication should be in an own thread!

Comment: It's a Multithreaded Server, I have edited the question with the complete code.

Comment: what to do if you can't/want to look at the os's queues. Create your own queue("buffer") and observe if/how it fills up and shape your trafic accordingly(if it fills you have to go down if it is rather empty go up). In more sophisticated queues(eg. the os's) you can set policies, that schedule packages and size queues according to priorities/policies.

Comment: If the other side is slow reading messages like these it would be more to the point to examine why, and speed it up.

Comment: Ok, so I will try to create my own buffer/queue and see if it works. @user207421 I can't influence a client's internet speed (1kb/s is just an example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is happening? Is data being buffered?

TCP write buffer will overflow.

And what happens depends on the Channel type you are using. If the channel is blocking in the blocking mode the Thread writing data will block waiting the client to receive data.

If the channel is in non-blocking mode y̶o̶u̶ ̶a̶r̶e̶ ̶m̶o̶s̶t̶ ̶l̶i̶k̶e̶l̶y̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶r̶e̶c̶e̶i̶v̶e̶ ̶I̶O̶E̶x̶c̶e̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ the write returns zero as specified in JavaDoc  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html#write(java.nio.ByteBuffer)

> A socket channel in non-blocking mode, for example, 
>   cannot write any more bytes than are free in the socket's 
>   output buffer.

`Socket`'s `OutputStream` is blocking by  definition.

Comment: Thanks, if it happens the server acts like it's not only blocking the thread from that client but all other threads as well. How do you recognize if the TCP write buffer gets overflown, so it's possible to close that socket if it happens.

Comment: @thom_22 If you want to know if it is possible to perform write operation without blocking you have to use NIO Selector api. Register the **non-blocking** channel with the `OP_WRITE` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SelectableChannel.html#register(java.nio.channels.Selector,%20int) and then poll the selector. You will get notified when it is possible to write some data without blocking.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at it.

Comment: You do not receive an `IOException`. `write()` returns zero. See the Javadoc. Don't post misinformation here.

Comment: @user207421 Yes, we do not.